# Trying to push same branch after it was merged remotely

Tags: git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I pushed my local branch called `correction` on github. My coworker merged it. Then I made some modification in my local branch `correction` and tried to push it again on github `git push origin correction`:

```
Counting objects: 20, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (20/20), 2.41 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 20 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (17/17), completed with 16 local objects.
To git@github.com:
   3a6138e..294a5e6  corrections -> corrections
```

I can see the push worked, however when I go on github I dont get the opportunity to create a pull request again.
What am I doing wrong/misundertanding ? what is the correct way to apply and merge my new modifications to the remote project

Comment: You don't get the notification 'you recently pushed...', but you can manually go 'create pull request' and select the branches

Answer (score 0):

once your pull request is merged delete the branch in remote and then push your changes from your local again. then the github will consider the branch as fresh branch and allows you to raise PR again.

Comment: Actually you don't need to remove the remote branch, you just need to push your changes and create a new pull request.